# Compute probability from expected values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

> Random variable $X$ can take the following values: $-2,-1,0,1,2$. Find the probabilities of having such values if $E(X)=E(X^3) = 0$, $E(X^2) = 1$ and $E(X^4) = 2$.

$E(X) = -2P(X=-2)-1P(X=-1)+0P(X=0) + 1P(X=1) + 2P(X=2)=0$
$E(X^3) = -8P(X=-2)-1P(X=-1)+0P(X=0) + 1P(X=1) + 8P(X=2)=0$
$E(X^2) = 4P(X=-2)+1P(X=-1)+0P(X=0) + 1P(X=1) + 4P(X=2)=1$
$E(X^4) = 16P(X=-2)+1P(X=-1)+0P(X=0) + 1P(X=1) + 16P(X=2)=2$

Solving this equations I get $0.042, 0.333, 0, 0.042, 0.333$
What is wrong with the approach?

Comment: Why should there be something wrong with the approach? I do observe that the probabilities do not sum to 1, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Michael Yes. I thought, if they do not sum to 1 then there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: How did you get those numbers?  You have 5 unknowns but 4 equations, ...you can only narrow down the choices by imposing the sum probability is 1. Overall your approach is fine, you are just making a mistake somewhere when you solve the linear equations.

Comment: Well, another equation is as you said the sum of probabilities is $1$. Actually, the third probability should be 0.292 instead of 0

Comment: I get a different answer when I solve the system of 5 equations and 5 unknowns: $$[p(-2);p(-1);p(0);p(1);p(2)]=[0.0417;
    0.3333;
    0.2500;
    0.3333;
    0.0417]$$  I just solved this with matlab.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-2a-b%2Bd%2B2f%3D0%2C+-8a-b%2Bd%2B8f%3D0%2C+4a%2Bb%2Bd%2B4f%3D1%2C+16a%2Bb%2Bd%2B16f%3D2%2C+a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%2Bf%3D1) gives $\left(\frac 1{24},\frac 13,\frac 14,\frac 13, \frac 1{24}\right)$

Comment: Probably, I made a mistake in calculations. Oh, I wrote $0$ in the wrong place of the matrix. I wrote $P(X=-2) + P(X=-1) + P(X=0) + P(X = 1) = 0$. Somehow, I forgot $P(X = 2)$ and inserted there $0$. Thank you all for help!